# How properly use SetMenuItemBitmaps to replace the default bitmap on a menu item?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to change the default bitmap on a menu item. Unfortunately, I'm not getting it to work.

The documentation of [`SetMenuItemBitmaps()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuitembitmaps) states that I should use the `GetSystemMetrics()` function with the `SM_CXMENUCHECK` and `SM_CYMENUCHECK` values to retrieve the default bitmap dimensions. I adjusted the `.bmp` file to these values, but it is still not working.

I probably have misunderstood something about the `SetMenuItemBitmaps()` function.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        SetMenuItemBitmaps(GetMenu(hWnd), ID_RED, MF_BYCOMMAND, LoadBitmap(hInst, L"red.bmp"), LoadBitmap(hInst, L"red.bmp"));
        return 0;
    }
    [...]
}
```

The menu item with the `ID_RED` id, whose bitmap I want to change:

[image]

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the reply. I didn't want to post too much code and have already tested if SetMenuItemBitmaps returns 0. However, the function always returns 1 this way. I will deal with memory leaks later. For now, I need to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `HMENU` handle of the menu that the `red` item directly belongs to.  You are using the top-level `HMENU`, but `red` is a child item of the *sub-menu* of the `color` item, which is a child item of the *sub-menu* of the `Menu` item, which is a child item of the top-level menu.

Once you have the top-level `HMENU`, use [`GetSubMenu()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsubmenu) or [`GetMenuItemInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmenuiteminfow) to get the `HMENU` of the *sub-menu* for the `Menu` item, then use that handle to get the `HMENU` of the *sub-menu* for the `color` item, and then finally use that handle to set the bitmaps for the `red` item.

Also, you are not checking whether `LoadBitmap()` is returning NULL or not. Even if it is not, you are responsible for destroying the bitmaps when you are done using them. So, even if this code worked, you would be leaking resources.

Comment: Ok, so if I have understood it right, I need to call `GetSubMenu(GetMenu(hWnd), 3)` (I have 4 top-level menus in total) and then from that menu I again need to call GetSubMenu. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: Your screenshot shows only 1 top-level menu item, `Menu`, not 4 items.  So, you would need something like `GetSubMenu(GetSubMenu(GetMenu(hWnd), 0), 2)` instead

Comment: Though, one thing I just noticed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-menus#accessing-menu-items-programmatically): "*If you specify the menu item **by command**, the menu **and its submenus** are searched for an item whose menu identifier equals the item number provided.*"  So this might be a moot point. Hard to say for sure, since you didn't show how you are creating your menu in the first place.

Comment: My whole menu looks like [this](https://imgur.com/CLNAtnc). I adjusted my code and it is working now. I will accept your answer above. Thanks a lot :)